# Excel - break concatenated string

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a text field in excel that looks like this:
123456 Smith, John

What I really want is to break this out so:
123456 is in a field called "employee id" AND
Smith, John is in another field called "employee name"

There can be anywhere from 3-6 numbers in the beginning part and then lastname, firstname will be consistent.

What is the best way to go about this?  I'd offer up what I've tried so far but I'm not really sure where to begin with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these two formulas (where A1 is the text field):

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)

=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1))
```

Use the first one to get the ID, and use the second one to get the name.  It requires that there be a space after the ID for every entry.

In use:

[image]